# zsh: alias'd commands stop working

Tags: zsh, alias

This keeps happening and I'm not sure why. How do I trace what zsh is actually trying to do, and why it starts ignoring my alias?

```
************@*******-MacBook-Pro$ reload
zsh: command not found: reload
✘ ************@*******-MacBook-Pro$ which reload
reload: aliased to source ~/.zshrc
```

This is zsh 5.9, with oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Just a sanity check: `which reload;reload` doesn't work, either, right? also, other alias do work, like `alias foo="echo bar"`, then executing `foo` does print "bar", right?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $options[aliases]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, alias expansion has been disabled somewhere through your `~/.zshrc`.

Alias expansion is normally enabled by default. Any one of:

```
unsetopt aliases
set +o aliases
setopt noaliases
options[aliases]=off
```

(and all other combinations with or without `no` prefixes, also bear in mind that case and underscores are ignored in option names) disables alias expansion.

You'd still be able to define aliases and they would still be reported in the output of `alias`/`which`/`whence`/`type`/`command -V` but they would no longer be expanded.

You'd need:

```
set -o aliases
```

(or other variants)

To reenable them, or remove the thing that disables them from your `~/.zshrc`.

```
$ alias reload='echo OK'
$ reload
OK
$ set +o aliases
$ reload
zsh: command not found: reload
$ which reload
reload: aliased to echo OK
$ set -o aliases
$ reload
OK
```

Comment: Correct - I eventually figured out which command caused the issue, then went hunting in my alias files and found an old function I'd written that included `unsetopt aliases`.